# MVC3 not redirecting after post

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following actions in my home controller. when i post to the `GetDistance()` it never goes to the /Home/ShowDistance page but stays on the /Home/Index page. I have checked that the `lat` and `lon` values are not null so the browser should be redirected to /Home/ShowDistance.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDistance(string lat, string lon)
{
    if (lat != null && lon != null)
    {
        Session["latlon"] = new LatLon { Latitude = double.Parse(lat), Longitude = double.Parse(lon) };
        return RedirectToAction("ShowDistance");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");    
}

public ActionResult ShowDistance()
{
    //...
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change it to a GET - and just hack the values in the URL?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your conditional statement to make sure you are in fact hitting that.  I'm guessing you're not if you're redirecting to `Index`.

Comment: if you actually step through in debug, does the correct Redirect get hit?

Comment: `ShowDistance()` does get hit after the post and the page does not redirect

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Is there anything on the page that could cause the page to refresh rather than post (eg async post and not preventing the default action of an anchor click)?

Comment: **You just can't redirect with ajax!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `Index.cshtml` view make sure that you specify the correct controller action to post to (because it has a different name than the one used to render the form). So instead of:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetDistance", null))
{
    ...
}
```

---

Or if you don't use a standard HTML `<form>` to invoke the `GetDistance` action but an AJAX call, then it's perfectly normal that the browser url stays at `/Home/Index`. The whole point of AJAX is to perform an asynchronous HTTP request to the server without navigating away from the current page (which in your case is `/Home/Index`). If this is the case and you want to redirect you will have to do it on the client in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDistance")',
    type: 'POST', 
    data: { lat: '123', lon: '456' },
    success: function(result) {
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    }
});
```

You will also have to modify your `GetDistance` POST action so that instead of redirecting it returns a JSON object containing the target url to redirect to that can be used in the success callback:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDistance(string lat, string lon)
{
    if (lat != null && lon != null)
    {
        Session["latlon"] = new LatLon { Latitude = double.Parse(lat), Longitude = double.Parse(lon) };
        return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("ShowDistance") });
    }
    return Json(new { redirectTo = Url.Action("Index") });
}
```

Obviously this kind of defeats the purpose of AJAX a little because as I said the whole point of AJAX is to perform asynchronous requests to the server and stay on the same page. So in this case you should probably stick with a standard HTML `<form>`.

Comment: In other words: **You just can't redirect with ajax!**

Comment: @gdoron, as I demonstrated in my answer you can redirect with AJAX but this totally defeats the purpose of AJAX.

Comment: Nope. This isn't redirection with ajax. **It's redirection after ajax success**. Totally different thing.

Comment: OK, you can call it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that either your lat and lon are not coming through in a way the model binder understands, or you are not in fact posting to GetDistance().  (as a side note, posting to something called Get.. is kind of odd).

Perhaps if you included some information from your view it would help.